# Why is collect statistics in databases called a resource consuming activity?

Tags: sql, database, teradata

Whenever we reach out to our Teradata DBA's to collect stats on specific tables, we get a feedback that it is a resource consuming activity and we will do it when system is relatively free or on the weekends when there is no load on system.

The tables for which stats collection is required are getting queried on intra-day basis. The explain plan shows "High confidence" if we collect stats on few columns.

So I just want to understand why stats collection is called as a resource consuming activity ? If we do not collect stats on tables which are getting loaded on intra-day basis, aren't we burdening the system by executing SQL's for which explain plans are saying "Collect stats" ?

Thanks!

Comment: The tables have to be completely read, taking locks into account, and the distributions of each column analyzed.  That sounds expensive to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistics collection is a maintenance activity that requires balance in a production Teradata environment. Teradata continues to make strides in improving the efficiency of statistics maintenance with each release of the database. If I recall correctly, one of the more recent improvements is to identify unused statistics or objects and bypass refreshing thee statistics during statistics collection. But it is a resource intensive operation on large tables with multiple sets of statistics present.

The frequency in which you collect statistics will vary based on the size of the table, how the table is loaded, and the number of statistics that exist on that table. Tables that are “flushed and filled” require more frequent statistics collection than tables where data is appended or updated in place. The former should have statistics collected after loading. The latter will vary based on the volume of data that changes vs. the time since the last collection of statistics. Stale statistics can mislead the optimizer or cause the optimizer to abandon them in favor of random sampling.

Furthermore, the larger a table grows in relation to the size of the system along with the known demographics of the table structure the ability to rely on sample statistics in place of full statistics comes into play. Being able to use the correct sample size reduces the cost of collecting the statistics.

It is not uncommon for statistics maintenance activities to be scheduled off hours or over the weekend. For large platforms, the collection of statistics across the system can be measured in hours. As a DBA I would be reluctant to refresh the statistics on a large production table in the middle of the day unless there was a query that was causing catastrophic problems (i.e. hot AMPing). Even then the remedy would be to prevent that query from running until statistics could be collected off hours.

If you have SLA’s defined in your environment and believe statistics collection would improve your ability to meet your SLAs, then a discussion with the DBA’s to come to a better understanding is necessary. Based on what you described, the DBA response is not surprising because they are trying to ensure the users receive the resources during the day.

Finally, if you have tables that are being loaded intra-day, the collection of SUMMARY statistics has low overhead and should be part of your ETL routine. Previously, collection of PARTITION statistics was also advisable irrespective of whether the table was actually partitioned, but I don’t recall if that has fallen out of favor in the most recent releases (16.xx) of Teradata. PARTITION statistics were also fairly low overhead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Too bad I can't +2 on this.

Comment: @ErwinSmout +1 for this one and your's one :) both of you explained thoroughly. thanks ! Answer credit goes to Rob because of the typing hard work ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes absence of stats may result in less optimal access paths and lesser performance than might otherwise be possible/achievable.

But yes collecting stats is a bit more intensive than looking whether a key value is present in a table.  So yes on loaded systems, it is not the wisest idea to add a stats collection to the load mix.

And at any rate, if the concerned tables are "loaded on an intraday basis", this means they are highly volatile and collecting stats for them might turn out to be not that useful after all, as any new load might render existing stats completely obsolete and/or off.  If you can provide reasonably accurate stats on a manual basis, do that.

EDIT

Oh yes, to answer the actual question you asked, "Why is collect statistics in databases called a resource consuming activity?" : because it consumes resources, and seriously above average compared to "normal" database transactions.